# How can I detect close form from border icon?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I've got Cancel and OK buttons in my form. They both do something and then call close form. How can I make the [x] button on form to call the Cancelclick?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the form is shown modally then you just need to test the value of `ModalResult`.  A value of mrCancel indicates that the cross was clicked.

I would be inclined to arrange that your buttons used their `ModalResult` properties to effect closing of the form.  Set the OK button's `ModalResult` to `mrOK` and that for the cancel button to `mrCancel`.

Answer (score 8):

Add this to your form's public declaration

```
procedure WMSysCommand(var MSG: TWMSysCommand); message WM_SYSCOMMAND;
```

then add the method

```
procedure TForm1.WMSYSCommand(var MSG:  TWMSysCommand);
begin
  if MSG.CmdType = SC_CLOSE then
  begin
     //Closing from border icon
  end;
  inherited;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OnCloseQuery events of the form.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  CanClose:= true;  //or not
  ButtonCancelClick(Self);
end;
```

If your buttons have their `modalresult` properties set, they will also call `OnCloseQuery` and this code will not work. In that case use David's answer.

Comment: No you can't use OnClose if you want to detect a click on the cross. That only calls OnCloseQuery.

Comment: Hmm, I think the `OnCloseQuery` will fire always when form closes, ie it will fire when user closes form via OK or Cancel button too. So with your code the ButtonCancelClick will be "fired" always... you have to use some additional flag to avoid that.

Comment: @Marjan: I just checked. Both OnCloseQuery and then OnClose are called. I hadn't expected anything else.

Comment: @Rudy: OnClose is not called in all circumstances, but OnCloseQuery is. It certainly used to be that way, and the advice always was to save data in "dirty" (edit) forms in the OnCloseQuery handler. But you are indeed right that both events are called when the close cross is clicked.

Comment: Could you give a circumstance when it is not called? Ok, if you set CanClose to False in OnCloseQuery, it won't, of course, but otherwise?

Comment: If you embed one form inside another, by setting the form's parent to another form or to a WinControl inside another form, neither the embedded form's OnClose or OnCloseQuery events trigger. In essence, the embedded form is treated like a frame.

Comment: @CaryJensen, of course, only the parent window gets window messages. The parent passes a only few messages on to children.